# Configure multiple domain on weblogic

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic12c

We need to configure a weblogic 12c version like the example below. However I can't find the configuration to add Admin_Server2 and Admin_Server3 to machines 2 and 3. See wrongly configured illustration.

Can you please help or provide pointers on how to configure Ideal Weblogic Configuration.

**Ideal Weblogic Configuration**

```
Machine1
Admin_Server1
Managed_Server1
Managed_Server2
Managed_Server3

Machine2
Admin_Server2
Managed_Server4
Managed_Server5
Managed_Server6

Machine3
Admin_Server3
Managed_Server7
Managed_Server8
Managed_Server9
```

**Weblogic Wrongly Configured**

```
Machine1
Admin_Server1
Managed_Server1
Managed_Server2
Managed_Server3

Machine2
Managed_Server4
Managed_Server5
Managed_Server6

Machine3
Managed_Server7
Managed_Server8
Managed_Server9
```

## Configuration 2

I am not sure if this is the correct way of creating multiple domains in weblogic.

```
1) From  /Middleware/oracle_common/common/bin/ path execute config.sh to run the GUI installer and create two more Weblogic domains.
2) Create AdminServer-2, Managed Servers and Machine2
3) Assign different ports to AdminServer2, Managed Servers and Machine2 with IP address set to currently configured IP address for the machine or VM
4) Repeat steps 2 and 3 for AdminServer3, MS-3 and Machine3 but and use ports which are not used by Servers on Domains 1 and 2.
5) Result is below

http://<IP_ADDRESS>:7001/console
    Machine1
    Admin_Server1
    Managed_Server1
    Managed_Server2
    Managed_Server3

http://<IP_ADDRESS>:7006/console
    Machine2
    Admin_Server2
    Managed_Server4
    Managed_Server5
    Managed_Server6

http://<IP_ADDRESS>:7011/console
    Machine3
    Admin_Server3
    Managed_Server7
    Managed_Server8
    Managed_Server9
```

Note I need to login to each weblogic server in order to configure further details on each managed servers.

Comment: The admin server is a singleton inside a WebLogic Domain. You will have to create a domain on each machine if you really need to realize your ideal configuration.

Comment: hi Emmanuel thanks for your comment, i have only setup one domain before and not multiple domains so I really don't have a clue as to how it would look like. Also i have new comments under configuration can you please check if am doing it right?

Comment: IP address and port must be a unique combination in your network, so you can always use the same port and just change IP adresses:
Machine 1: 
Admin Server : IP1:7001
Machine 2:
Admin Server : IP2:7001
Machine 3:
Admin Server : IP3:7001
and so on,

Comment: The IP address is the same for all Servers because oracle weblogic domains are residing on one physical server. The port however is different as instructed on oracle documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand what a WebLogic Domain is.

A WebLogic domain could be seen as a group of resources which are grouped and configured together, in a domain. The domain configuration is managed through the admin server. So, each domain has one and only one admin server. And every admin server belongs to only one domain.

From what I have understood is that you want to create a separate domain per machine. So you have to install and configure a WebLogic domain separately on each and every machine. During installation you don't you should only configure one machine.